# Why go is parsing my timestamp with Local location instead of UTC

Tags: parsing, go, time, timestamp-with-timezone

I don't understand this behaviour (or the doc) of this: 
https://play.golang.org/p/vz2UTz-3Yy

On the playground, it return the expected results:

```
t = 2015-06-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
t.Location() = UTC
parsed = 2015-06-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
parsed.Location() = UTC
```

On my mac, I get:

```
t = 2015-06-01 00:00:00 +0000 +0000
t.Location() =
parsed = 2015-06-01 00:00:00 +0000 +0000
parsed.Location() =
```

The problem is, if I create a date with

```
time.Date(2015, time.June, 01, 00, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
```

the 2 times are different, because one has a location ("UTC"), and the other not (or "Local"). I'm bit lost here.

Thanks

Comment: It's even stranger for me. If I run is with time zone set in the shell (`TZ=MSK go run foo.go`) it gives me UTC. By the way, if you want your dates to be UTC you can replace `+00:00` with `Z`.

Comment: I don't want to, that's a json output from postgresql (and it's valid) :)

Comment: The time package is mocked in the playground, results may be different on the real runtime - https://blog.golang.org/playground

Answer (score 2):

> When parsing a time with a zone offset like -0700, if the offset corresponds to a time zone used by the current location (Local), then Parse uses that location and zone in the returned time. Otherwise it records the time as being in a fabricated location with time fixed at the given zone offset. [[time.Parse](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse)]

`t.Location` (a name) is only set when the local offset matches the offset that is in the parsed date string. You probably have a different time zone set.

So the offset is recorded but the location is not looked up.

Comment: My english must be too poor, because that part of the doc is very unclear to me :(

Comment: the problem is, I need to compare this timestamp. It's using a +00:00 offset, so I should compare it with `time.Date(2015, time.June, 01, 00, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)` (my test shouldn't depend on my location). Here, the 2 times differ :(

Comment: Then use [`time.ParseInLocation`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#ParseInLocation) instead.

Comment: I don't parse location directly, Unmarshall does, and I don't have control on this :(

Comment: Looks like a go bug to me. Parsing timestamps with a specified offset should REALLY not depend on my location. UTC is UTC, not matter where I am

Comment: @Gravis And it *is* UTC, only the location name is not looked up.

Comment: I understand that, but this makes reflect.deepEqual failing when comparing structs. So again, `time.Date(2015, time.June, 01, 00, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)` should return the exact same date, but they are still different. Do you think I should open an issue in the go repo?

Comment: I see. In that case it is probably best to open an issue and discuss it there, yes. When you do, please update your question with the link to the issue.